# Fractional product Hölder inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

Recently I needed a result of the following form $$||f^\alpha||_{L^p} \leq ||f||_{L^q}^{\alpha}$$ where $\alpha >0$ is a real number and we have the usual Hölder condition $$\frac{1}{p} = \frac{\alpha}{q}$$

I know the usual Hölder inequality holds for a countable product of functions. But is the above true? I imagine maybe we should take $\alpha$ to be at least $\geq 1$. By writing $\alpha = n + r$ where $n$ is a natural number and $r \in [0,1)$ we can apply the regular Hölder inequality to $f^{\alpha} = f^nf^r$. So I think it would reduce it to the case of showing that $$||f^r||_{L^q} \leq ||f||^r_{L^q}$$ however I can't see how to proceed here. I feel like some type of interpolation argument might be helpful here but not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is $q = \alpha p$, so that
$$\int (|f|^\alpha)^p  = \int |f|^{\alpha p} = \int |f|^q.$$ Thus $$\|f^\alpha\|_p = \left( \int (|f|^\alpha)^p \right)^{1/p} = \left( \int |f|^q \right)^{1/p} = \left( \int |f|^q \right)^{\alpha/q} = \|f\|^\alpha_q.$$

Comment: Ah thanks. Can't believe I over thought it this much!

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any Hölder inequality here but just the definition of the $L^p$ norm:
$$
\|f^\alpha\|_{L^p} = \left(\int |f^\alpha|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p} =  \left(\int |f|^{\alpha p}\right)^\frac{\alpha}{q} = \|f\|_{L^q}^\alpha$$
But perhaps I didn't understand well your problem?
Warning that for it to define a norm you should have $p\geq 1$ and $q\geq 1$ (and so $\alpha \leq q$)

Comment: Yes I agree now that I was just overthinking it. I suppose I still am interested  in the case holders inequality for $f$ raised to a general real number since I've only seen it stated for countable products of functions (i.e. $f$ raised to an integral power). Not sure how one would need to change the conditions to make this a real question though.